# what does $* and * stand for exactly in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting and I ran into several `$*` and `*` in the codes (not double quoted). What I understand about them is that they all stand for all the other possibilities except for the ones mentioned. e.g.

```
echo "$1"
$*
```

If the input line is

```
A B C D E F
```

Then `$*` here stands for B-F. Am I right?

Also for `*`, it's often been found in `case`. It's used as `else` in C, right?

Answer (score 3):

`$*` is each of the arguments passed to the script as words. And it is usually wrong. `"$@"` is almost always preferred, since it keeps each argument together even if composed of multiple words.

`*` is a glob wildcard that says "match anything" (except hidden files under most circumstances). In `case` it will match any text.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. Does `$*` always need to be double quoted?

Comment: Who cares. You shouldn't be using `$*` in the first place.